# Checking for 3 in a row in random 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

```
import pprint, random

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(1)
grid = []
for x in range(6):
    orbs = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    random.shuffle(orbs)
    y_list = []
    for y in range(5):
        y_list.append(orbs[y])
    grid.append(y_list)

pp.pprint(grid)
```

Ok, I have the above code written out to print a 2d Array of a 6(R)x5(C) matrix\board. Each coordinate in the board should generate randomly on each loop, which is what I want.

Now, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to check for 3-in-a-row matches (vertical or horizontal only) such that a random board like this never has them occur.

Should I create the board first, then check for a condition (3-in-a-row) first? Or should I be coding in the condition to each row\column as they are generated? Is there a python module I should be looking at that already does something along these lines?

EDIT:

Here is an example of an output that would be unacceptable:

```
[[5, 2, 5, 2, 2],
 [5, 4, 1, 5, 2],
 [1, 1, 0, 5, 3],
 [4, 4, 4, 0, 1],
 [0, 5, 0, 0, 3],
 [5, 3, 4, 2, 5]]
```

And here is an acceptable one:

```
[[4, 1, 4, 4, 5],
 [1, 3, 0, 1, 4],
 [1, 5, 4, 4, 0],
 [5, 2, 0, 4, 3],
 [5, 4, 2, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 5, 0, 4]]
```

Comment: `range(0, 6)` is usually spelled `range(6)``

Comment: @Mike-Graham Indeed. Updated to reflect that.

Comment: Your shuffle is unnecessary given your later `random.choice`. It looks like what you mean could be as easily said `[[random.randrange(6) for _ in range(5)] for __ in range(6)]`.

Comment: For logic on searching diagonals, look up `Eight Queens Problem` for solutions in python. As for your question, I would get the coordinates of all `0`s,all `1`s, etc., and apply test from top to bottom on each group of numbers.

Comment: (Or `numpy.random.randint(0, 5, (6, 5))`)

Comment: And: `grid = [[random.choice(orbs) for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]`

Comment: @MikeGraham Ah, I see the redundancy. Updated the code to reflect.

Comment: @hughdbrown Can you explain what you mean by "apply test"? I'm unfamiliar with that as of yet in my python learning.

Comment: @bhamhawker, Your current code eliminated the `random.choice`, but you probably wanted to eliminate the `random.shuffle`. You changed it so that each row cannot have repeats.

Comment: BTW, if you really did want `y_list = []; for y in range(5): y_list.append(orbs[y])`, that's spelled `y = orbs[:5]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In numpy

```
> a = np.array(
[[5, 2, 5, 2, 2],
 [5, 4, 1, 5, 2],
 [1, 1, 0, 5, 3],
 [4, 4, 4, 0, 1],
 [0, 5, 0, 0, 3],
 [5, 3, 4, 2, 5]])
> (a[:,:-2:] == a[:,1:-1:]) & (a[:,:-2:] == a[:,2::]) # start of horizontal runs
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
> (a[:-2:,:] == a[1:-1:,:]) & (a[:-2:,:] == a[2::,:]) # start of vertical runs
> (a[:-2:,:-2:] == a[1:-1:,1:-1:]) & (a[:-2:,:-2:] == a[2::,2::]) # start of diagonal runs
```

You can use `numpy.where(a[:,:-2:] == a[:,1:-1:]) & (a[:,:-2:] == a[:,2::])` to get the coordinates of the start of the runs.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I create the board first, then check for a condition (3-in-a-row) first?

Yep, that sounds like the easiest way!

> Or should I be coding in the condition to each row\column as they are generated?

I wouldn't! That would be way more complicated. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
def validate(board):
    Hdiff = np.abs(np.diff(board))
    Vdiff = np.abs(np.diff(board.T))
    kernel = np.ones((1,2))
    test = convolve2d(Hdiff, kernel, 'valid')
    test2 = convolve2d(Vdiff, kernel, 'valid')
    x1,y1 =  np.nonzero(test == 0)
    y2,x2 =  np.nonzero(test2 == 0)

    if len(x1):
        board[x1,y1] = np.random.randint(0, 5, len(x1))
    if len(x2):
        board[x2,y2] = np.random.randint(0, 5, len(x2))

    if len(x1) or len(x2):
        return validate(board)
    else:
        return board

myBoard = np.random.randint(0, 5, (6, 5))
myBoard[1,2:5] = [3, 3, 3]
myBoard[0:3, 0] = [1, 1, 1]
print myBoard
print validate(myBoard)
```

Original:

```
[[1 0 0 0 3]
 [1 3 3 3 3]
 [1 1 0 0 0]
 [1 3 4 4 1]
 [0 1 2 0 4]
 [2 3 2 3 1]]
```

Validated:

```
[[4 4 0 0 3]
 [4 1 2 3 3]
 [1 1 2 0 0]
 [1 3 4 4 1]
 [0 1 2 0 4]
 [2 3 2 3 1]]
```

Using a convolution to detect invalid rows\columns.